# UINavigationBar frame animation not possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

UINavigationBars within a UINavigationController. . . they don't participate in frame animations. Useful, but exactly ***not*** what I want right now. Is there a way to turn this off?

I know I could set the showsNagitationBar property to hidden, and add my own to the view, put am looking at possible alterntives.

**What I'm Trying to Achieve:**

I've put my UINavigationController into a (screen-sized) container view, and want to slide it across to reveal a side menu. . last time that I did this I had custom push/pop methods on the RootVC, and my own navigation bar - worked fine, though a fair amount of boiler-plate code to set up.

This time I've got the same kind of requirement - main content is push/pop based, and some auxiliary VCs that can be revealed from the side. And so for another approach, and considering that this app's look and feel is very standard, I just included a UINavigationController within the RootVC and expected it to work the same.

However the UINavigationBar stays anchored in place, while the rest of the content within the container view moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but when using a navigation controller, the entirety of what you see on screen (your top view controller's view PLUS your navigation bar) is rooted in the Navigation Controller's view.

This means that if you do something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    frame.size.width -= 30;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;
}];
```

You will get your view AND the navigation bar to shrink.

EDIT: You can add/remove the sliding-in views to the navigation controller's view where it is appropriate (for example the nav controller is your root view controller, you could do it in your appdelegate's `didFinishLaunch:` method). The following code would show an entirely red view sliding in from the left. In your case, this view would be the one from your side view controller.

```
UIView *left = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
left.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGRect ff = left.frame;
ff.origin.x = -ff.size.width;
left.frame = ff;

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:left];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 50;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;
}];
```

Is something like this what you were looking for?

Comment: Actually you're right. It behaves just like any other view. I was using the Paperfold lib and had added my main content container as a subview, instead of to the centerContentView property in paperfold.